# Why is object reference is always required in Main function to call a method of child class?

Tags: c#, inheritance

I would like to know why an object reference is always required in the `Main` method to call a method of the child class.

However we can call the `Main` method directly by a method name from other methods:

```
using System; 

class MainProgram : Parent_Class 
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Project1_Child p = new Project1_Child(); 

        p.PI_add();   //->  Object reference is required     
    }


    public void non_Main_method() 
    {
        PI_add();     //-> No Object reference is required  

    }
}

public class Parent_Class
{


    public void PI_add()
    {

        Console.WriteLine("-------------");

    }

}
```

Why is this?

Comment: That's because Main is static. Read about static methods and you will figure

Answer (score 7):

As the other answer notes, you need to learn the difference between static and instance methods.  The point of this answer is to get you on a path of correct terminology and thought about calls to instance methods. You say:

> I would like to know why an object reference is always required in the Main method to call a method of the child class.

Let's break it down.

- A *call* is a kind of *member access*. That is, you are *accessing a member of a type* when you make a call. In this case the members you are accessing are *methods*.
- Every member access has a *receiver*.  The receiver is the thing whose member is being accessed.
- Aside: The jargon "receiver" might seem confusing, why "receiver"? What is being "received" when you access a member of a type?  This jargon comes from the idea that object oriented programming is about *sending messages to objects* and then getting answers back. When you call `x = foo.Bar(123)` you are "sending a message" to `foo` about what computation you wish `foo` to perform, and `foo` sends you the result back to put in `x`.
- **Do not think of the receiver as an object reference**. "Object" and "reference" both have very specific meanings in C#.  The receiver is an *expression*, and the type checker must verify that it has certain properties. In some cases the receiver must be a valid object reference, but not all, as we'll see.
- Some members are "static" and some are "instance".  The difference is: a static member requires that the receiver name the type itself.  An instance member requires that the receiver be an instance of the type.
- Again, we have a jargon problem. "Instance" is obvious, but "static" is not. There really is no good reason for "static" anymore; historically a call to a static member could be determined *by static (that is, compile time) analysis*. Some instance member calls are dispatched dynamically by the runtime. VB calls static methods "shared" which makes more sense; they are "shared" amongst the instances of a type.
- There's a subtlety here, in that the receiver of an instance method must be a *valid* instance of that type. If the receiver is a reference type then it must evaluate to a non-null reference *at runtime*. The compiler only checks that its type is known to the compiler, not that it is non-null. This may change in C# 8!
- There's another subtlety here, in that value types require that the receiver be not just a *value* but a *variable* of the appropriate type. The C# compiler will in some cases create a variable for you when necessary, but again, this is a subtlety that you can learn about later.
- "Elision" is the concept in the study of languages that we can "elide" unnecessary words from sentences and still understand them. If I said "Do you have any dishes that need washed?" you'd understand the sentence even though grammatically it ought to be "that need to be washed".
- Now we come to the crux of the misunderstanding. **C# allows you to elide the receiver in several specific cases**.
- If the member you are accessing is an instance member, and you are accessing it from an instance member, then you can elide the receiver, and C# will assume you meant `this.`
- If the member you are accessing is a static member, and you are accessing it from any member of its class, then you can elide the receiver and C# will assume you meant, in this case, `MainProgram.`

This then explains your observations.

- In `Main` you call `PI_add`. That's an instance member, so it needs a receiver that is an instance. If you were calling *from* an instance member then C# would assume that you elided `this.`, but you are calling from a static member. Therefore the receiver is required, and it is an error to elide it.
- In `non_main_method`, an instance method, you call `PI_add`. It's an instance method, so the elided receiver is assumed to be `this.`

That's enough information to get you going down a more productive path. When you learn about delegates and extension methods you'll see that there are additional subtleties here about what exactly the receiver is and how the compiler treats it.

Comment: "That's enough information to get you going down a more productive path". Ha. That's enough information for a blog post! Yet again, you leave me no choice but to upvote your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Because the `main` method is a static method, and the `non_Main_method` is an instance method.

static methods belongs to the type, not to a specific instance, so in order to execute instance methods in them, you must first create an instance of the type.

From [static (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static):

> Use the static modifier to declare a static member, which belongs to the type itself rather than to a specific object.

From [Static Classes and Static Class Members (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members):

> Static methods and properties cannot access non-static fields and events in their containing type, and they cannot access an instance variable of any object unless it is explicitly passed in a method parameter.

Though that last part is not accurate - [You are allowed to create an instance of the class inside a static method](http://rextester.com/UDM53954) - it does not have to be passed as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Calling a nonstatic method (like PI_add() in your example) of a class is really just a shorthand notation for

```
this.PI_add();
```

and that in turn is (basically) just a shorthand notation for calling an (almost) equivalent static method (which doesn't actually exist in your namespace)

```
PI_add_static(this);
```

But if you are trying to call PI_add() from a static method like Main, there is never ever a this-object in a static function. That is because a static method - by definition - does not belong to any object. Thus what you are trying to do amounts to calling

```
PI_add_static(); // argument missing
```

where you have missed passing the argument. Now it might be clear to you that this cannot work.

BTW: be aware that I said "basically" when comparing PI_add_static(this) to this.PI_add(). In fact what makes them different in reality is at the core of all object-orientation: the ability of a non-static method to select (we say dispatch) the right implementation among several derived object types.

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't have something to do with inheritance, simplify the problem and move the method `PI_add` to `MainProgramSimply`.

`non_Main_method` is instance (non static) method, it means it shares the state of the current object, with all its instance members like `PI_add` method

```
public void non_Main_method() 
    {
        PI_add();     //-> No Object reference is required  
    }
```

so yes ,

> No Object reference is required

because calling an instance member doesn't need to be called on an object reference inside another instance member of the same class, because you will be calling `non_Main_method` through an instance (right?), though, you can use `this` keyword, it means: call *this* member on the current class instance: `this.PI_add();` but you can omit it, because you always writing for the current instance.

But on the other hand a static method is more likely a global member that is accessible on the class level not the instance level, so when you want to call an instance member you need to specify which instance exactly you want to call on.