# How can a static method invoke a virtual method?

Tags: c#, .net, static, overriding, overloading

There are a few things one can do when writing one's own equality logic for custom objects. Two of those practices include  overloading the `==` operator and overriding the `obj.Equals()` method.
Below, we do just that for parent class `Animal` and child class `Hominoidea`.

```
public class Animal
{
   public static bool operator ==(Animal x, Animal y)
   {
      return object.Equals(x, y);
   }

   public override bool Equals(object obj)
   { ... }

   ...
}

public class Hominoidea : Animal
{
   public static bool operator ==(Hominoidea x, Hominoidea y)
   {
      return object.Equals(x, y);
   }

   public override bool Equals(object obj)
   { ... }

   ...
}
```

In the case that we went to be able to easily compare a manner of animals regardless of their derived classes (Hominoidea, Felidae, etc), we'd take advantage of the simple logic of the base class and maybe write something like:

```
static void DisplayWhetherEqual(Animal animal1, Animal animal2)
{
   if (animal1 == animal2)
   {
      Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0,12} == {1}", animal1, animal2));
   }
   else
      Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0,12} != {1}", animal1, animal2));
}
```

If we pass in `Hominoidea` objects, the code will first execute the `static` overload `==` for the `Animal` class but then execute the virtual `object.Equals(x, y)` for the child class, `Hominoidea` class.

When comparing both these `Hominoidea` classes as `Animal`s, **how does the compiler invoke the correct virtual `object.Equals()` method inside the `static` operator method?** I thought everything inside a `static` method had to also be `static`?

Comment: Imagine if you called `x.Equals(y)` instead of `object.Equals(x, y)`

Comment: Both of your `==` overloads are calling the same _static_ method.

Comment: Check out the implementation of [`object.Equals`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/object.cs,68)

Comment: You might also want to read the answers to [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49477336/why-is-object-reference-is-always-required-in-main-function-to-call-a-method-of) (especially Eric Lippert's answer)

Answer (score 4):

Static methods can certainly access instance methods; you wouldn't be able to do anything very interesting without them. The thing a static class lacks is its own instance (the keyword `this` is undefined from inside a static method). But you can call instance methods on any object that is passed to it or otherwise made available.

So while you cannot do this

```
class MyClass
{
    static void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(this.ToString());  //Does not compile
    }
}
```

you most certainly can do this

```
class MyClass
{
    static void Print(MyClass instance)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(instance.ToString());  //Compiles, because it references an object that was passed in
    }
}
```

And this

```
class MyClass
{
    static private MyClass _anInstance = new MyClass();

    static void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(_anInstance.ToString());  //Compiles, because it references an object instance held in a static variable
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> I thought everything inside a static method had to also be static

What made you think so? There is no such a rule. Static methods are not attached to a specific instance of the class (that's why they call them `Shared` in VB, meaning they're shared between all instances), but otherwise they are no different from instance methods.

Consider this

```
public class Person {
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public static string GetInitials(Person person) {
        return person.FirstName[0].ToString() + person.LastName[0].ToString();
    }
}
```

The `static` method `GetInitials()` can access the properties of the instance that is passed to it. So you can write this code:

```
var p = new Person();
p.FirstName = "Joe";
p.LastName = "Smith";
Console.WriteLine(Person.GetInitials(p));
```

Comment: "I thought everything inside a static method had to also be static" What made me think this was a misunderstanding, an exaggeration really, of what happens at compile time. I thought because the method cant be instantiated, then how could it dynamically invoke a virtual of something else. I just grossly extended the line of thinking and made false assumptions. Thank you for the answer.